# typeahead and foundation results appear cut off

Tags: html, css

So I have this html:

```
<form name="searchForm" role="form" ng-submit="controller.navigate()">
    <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="small-10 columns typeahead-icon">
            <!-- If we take the filter out, it will match all parts of the object -->
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="controller.selected" typeahead="item.value + ' ' + item.title + ' ' +  item.detail for item in controller.search($view)" />
            <i ng-show="controller.autoComplete.loading" class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>                        
        </div>
        <div class="small-2 columns">
            <button type="submit" class="button postfix">Go</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, I am using an inline form to display my typeahead control. The problem is, with **.columns** having **position: relative** the list that contains the results is hidden behind the end of the columns div. I can't add overflow to the div because of my design. What I would like is for the results list to appear over the top of everything.
I have created a codepen to show you what is happening:

http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/gpoXeg

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this took some time to fix, the answer is very simple.
All I had to do was add:

```
overflow: visible;
```

to the parent element which I didn't want the height to change (in this case **.tile.block**) and it fixed the issue.
The codepen above has been changed to reflect this change.